# Getting errors when trying to insert data into a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle, ora-00911

I am using python 2.7 and the cx_Oracle module.  When I try to run the following query:

```
UPDATE bs_cart
    SET qty = qty + :moreBooks
    WHERE userid = :userID 
    AND isbn = :bookNumber;

IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO bs_cart
    (userid,isbn)
    VALUES
    (:userID,:bookNumber)
```

using `Cursor.execute()` from `cx_Oracle` I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

When I put it in SQL plus it says:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "IF SQL%ROW..." - rest of line ignored.
```

I am trying to make the cart `UPDATE` if a user already has the selected book in the cart and `INSERT` if there are no current copies of the book they want in the cart.

The execute method looks like:

```
ds.execute(sql,moreBooks=howMany,userID=userLoggedIn,bookNumber=booksToBuy)
```

and each of the parameters are user generated using `rawinput()` and then checked against a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose your statements in `begin`/`end` Oracle blocks.

Something like:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE bs_cart
  SET qty = qty + :moreBooks
  WHERE userid = :userID 
  AND isbn = :bookNumber;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
     INSERT INTO bs_cart (userid,isbn)
     VALUES (:userID,:bookNumber);
END;
```

Comment: I enclosed with `BEGIN` and `END` but now I am getting an error that says `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare else elseif end exit . . .`.  It mentions `END` as something it expected so why is it failing?

Comment: You need a semicolon at the end of the INSERT statement, plus an "END IF" before the END.

Comment: When I added the END IF; along with your suggestion it worked.  Thanks Pablo and Griffey.